# I am facing the below error on Rabbitmq certificate creation.what is the error. Please explain me with clear solution

Tags: openssl, rabbitmq, erlang, ssl-certificate, sslhandshakeexception

SSL: 1062: error:{error,{badmatch,{error,enoent}}} /etc/ssl/rabbitmq/cacert.pem

SSL: hello: ./ssl_handshake.erl:172:Fatal error: protocol version

SSL: hello: ./ssl_handshake.erl:172:Fatal error: protocol version

SSL: 1084: error:{try_clause,{error,enoent}} /etc/ssl/rabbitmq/cert.pem

[{ssl_manager,cache_pem_file,1},

{ssl_certificate,file_to_certificats,1},

{ssl_connection,init_certificates,5},

{ssl_connection,ssl_init,2},

{ssl_connection,init,1},

SSL WARNING: Ignoring a CA cert as it could not be correctly decoded.

```
                 {ssl_options,[],verify_none,

                     {#Fun<ssl.1.30290474>,[]},

                     false,false,undefined,1,"/etc/ssl/rabbitmq/cert.pem",

                     undefined,"/etc/ssl/rabbitmq/key.pem",undefined,

                     undefined,undefined,"/etc/ssl/rabbitmq/cacert.pem",

                     #Fun<ssl.0.52397447>,true,18446744073709551900,false,

                 17080394,ssl_session_cache,undefined,undefined,false,

 {ssl_cipher,filter,2},

 {ssl_handshake,select_session,8},

 {ssl_handshake,hello,4},

 {ssl_connection,hello,2},

 {ssl_connection,next_state,3},

"{'EXIT',\n    {{{badmatch,\n          {error,\n              {asn1,\n                  {'Type not compatible with table constraint',\n                      {{component,'Type'},\n                       {value,{5,<<>>}},\n                       {unique_name_and_value,id,{1,2,840,113549,1,1,11}}}}}}},\n      [{public_key,pkix_decode_cert,2},\n       {ssl_cipher,filter,2},\n       {ssl_handshake,select_session,8},\n       {ssl_handshake,hello,4},\n       {ssl_connection,hello,2},\n       {ssl_connection,next_state,3},\n       {gen_fsm,handle_msg,7},\n       {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3}]},\n     {gen_fsm,sync_send_all_state_event,[<0.2407.0>,start,infinity]}}}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the important part of the error:

```
error:{error,{badmatch,{error,enoent}}} /etc/ssl/rabbitmq/cacert.pem
```

`ENOENT` is a standard Unix error code meaning that the file does not exist. It looks as though two of the expected files are not present, based on the error output. Another option is that there may be a typo in your configuration.

Comment: But i am sure that there is no typo in the configuration and the file also exists on the same name as specified. Please let me know os there any other possibilities?

Comment: Not that I know of. `enoent` is pretty definitive. You can provide the output of `ls -la /etc/ssl` and `ls -la /etc/ssl/rabbitmq` and maybe something will show up. You should also provide your complete RabbitMQ configuration file.